# Fetch JSON data by service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to fetch particular category by id. I have populated dummyjson data using $http method.I am unable to do this. I have pass id from my services to controller but it returns null. Here i my code

service.js:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('myApp')
        .factory('registerService', function ($http) {
         var category=[];
            return {
                getAll:function(){
                    return $http.get('json/dummyJson.json').then(function(response){
                        category=response.data;
                        return category;
                    });
                },
                getUser:function(category_id)
                {
                    for(var i=0;i<category.length;i++){
                        console.log(category.length);
                        if(category[i].id === parseInt(category_id)){
                            return category[i];
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }


            }
        });
})();
```

controller.js:

```
 (function() {
        angular.module('myApp').controller('registrationCtrl1', function ($scope, $stateParams, registerService) {
          console.log('inside registerCtrl2');
          $scope.categoryName=registerService.getUser($stateParams.category_id);
            console.log($stateParams.category_id);
            console.log($scope.categoryName);
        });
    })();
```

Comment: `return category[i].Name` .you are returning whole object.

Comment: Also did you check if `$stateParams.category_id` value is not null and getting passed to service?And most important observation is how are you persisting `category` array.Most likely that is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `category` will have value within `getUser`, but that won't happen. The only place where category is populated is `getAll`, but since you are not calling getAll, category is not populated. Chnage your method as below and it will work:

```
getUser: function(category_id) {
  return $http.get('json/dummyJson.json').then(function(response){
    category=response.data;
    for(var i=0;i<category.length;i++) {
      console.log(category.length);
      if(category[i].id === parseInt(category_id)){
        return category[i];
      }
    }

    return null;
 });
}
```

Since your method returns a promise now you need to handle the promise in a callback in your controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('registrationCtrl1', function ($scope, $stateParams, registerService) {
      console.log('inside registerCtrl2');
      registerService.getUser($stateParams.category_id)
        .then(function (response) {
          $scope.categoryName= response;
          console.log($stateParams.category_id);
          console.log($scope.categoryName);
        });
    });
```

Comment: this is good catch.however OP stated `$stateParams.category_id` is null which is passed in parameter.

Comment: Yeah. That will also be the case if you don't pass id in your stateParams

Comment: Can you provide your updaed code in a plunkr or jsbin?

Comment: You can use $filter service for a more "angular" way of filtering. For example: $filter('filter')(category, {id: category_id})